# Django -- Conditional Login Redirect

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I am working on a Django application that will have two types of users: Admins and Users. Both are groups in my project, and depending on which group the individual logging in belongs to I'd like to redirect them to separate pages. Right now I have this in my settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'admin_list'
```

This redirects all users who sign in to 'admin_list', but the view is only accessible to members of the Admins group -- otherwise it returns a 403. As for the login view itself, I'm just using the one Django provides. I've added this to my main urls.py file to use these views:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

How can I make this so that only members of the Admins group are redirect to this view, and everyone else is redirected to a different view?

Comment: Are you using your own login view or reusing Django's generic one? If your own view, then show us the view.

Comment: I'm using Django's generic login view, just using this in my main urls.py url(r'^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

Comment: Update the question with that info please. No one can help you if you do not give all the information needed to debug it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Create a separate view that redirects user's based on whether they are in the admin group.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def login_success(request):
    """
    Redirects users based on whether they are in the admins group
    """
    if request.user.groups.filter(name="admins").exists():
        # user is an admin
        return redirect("admin_list")
    else:
        return redirect("other_view")
```

Add the view to your `urls.py`,

```
url(r'login_success/$', views.login_success, name='login_success')
```

then use it for your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_success'
```

Comment: I added the following to myapp/urls.py and it worked perfectly! url(r'login_success/$', views.login_success, name='login_success'),

Answer (score 5):

I use an intermediate view to accomplish the same thing:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/wherenext/"
```

then in my urls.py:

```
(r'^wherenext/$', views.where_next),
```

then in the view:

```
@login_required
def wherenext(request):
    """Simple redirector to figure out where the user goes next."""
    if request.user.is_staff:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin-home'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user-home'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_response(request, **kwargs):
  if kwargs.get('something'):
    redirect(to='https://example.com/foo')
  else:
    redirect(to='index')

urlpatterns = [
    path('redirect', redirect_response, name='redirect'),
    path('index',index_response ,name='index')
]
```