# Django login redirection

Tags: python, django, redirect, authentication

I'm working on two differents apps I created called ticket and money. I would like that after the login, user who's staff (user.is_staff) could be redirect to the homepage of money app (money_homepage) and user who's not staff redirect to the homepage of ticket (ticket_homepage).

I already looked for the function login in contrib/auth/views.py and in registration/login.html :

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% if next %} {{ next }} {% else %} ../{% endif %}"/>
```

But I didn't find my answer yet.
Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824004/django-conditional-login-redirect/16824337#16824337) might help.

Comment: No it doesn't help me, but nice try.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why it didn't help? It exactly does what you wanted. Instead of one redirection you do two there.

Comment: In reality, the apps "ticket" is the helpdesk module, which already have 3 differents redirects. I don't need how I do it but where I edit it.