# How to get the username from django.contrib.auth (Django built-in login system)?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am very new to Python and Django, and am looking at a code that uses the Django built-in login system (django.contrib.auth.login).

After the user has logged in, I would like to redirect the user to an appropriate URL based on the users privilege. For example, some usernames have admin privileges, while some are just regular users. However, after the "login" button is clicked, the user is always redirected to the same URL.

In order to redirect the user differently, I would have to check the username, and check what privileges that user has. However, I can not find any way to fetch the username from django.contrib.auth.login. It is as if the username just disappears after it has been authenticated.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: You should show the code you are using and indicate where the username "disappears".

Comment: Authenticated user is stored in request object, under 'user' attribute. You can retrieve it simply in your view using 'request.user' or 'self.request.user' if you use class based views. This is well explained [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests).

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824004/django-conditional-login-redirect/16824337#16824337) might help.

Answer (score 1):

The user's name can be found here:

```
request.user.username
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're able to log him you should have something like that (partial code here):

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
login(request, user)

if user.is_admin and user.is_staff:
    return HttpRedirectResponse('/some/path')
elif user.idontknow:
    return HttpRedirectResponse('/some/other/path')
...
else:
    return HttpRedirectResponse('/default/redirect/url')
```

Answer (score 0):

The login view supports the "next" parameter. So in your form template you can add it like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/go/here/if/successful" />
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

To do this in the view, while respecting the next parameter and provide different defaults based on the user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

class MyLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_redirect_url(self):
        next = super(MyLoginView, self).get_redirect_url()
        if not next:
            user = self.request.user  # see form_valid and auth.login()
            if user.is_staff:
                return '/staff/goes/here'

        return next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code in views and bind url to index function

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.user.is_admin and request.user.is_active:
        return render(request, 'admin-page.html')
    return render(request, 'user-page.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

In login template some like:

```
<form action="/login/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
</form>
```

And in backend like [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) says:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
user = authenticate(username='john', password='secret')
if user is not None:
    # A backend authenticated the credentials
else:
    # No backend authenticated the credentials
```